# Proving parametricity for Gallina functions

Tags: functional-programming, semantics, coq

I have the following definitions

```
Definition nat'' {X : Type} := (X -> X) -> X -> X.
Definition nat' := forall (X : Type), @nat'' X.
```

And when I wanted to prove a certain property I ended up in the following situation:

```
  m : nat'
  H : 0 = m nat S 0
  X : Type
  s : X -> X
  z : X
  ============================
  m X s z = z
```

which should be some kind of free theorem! Specifically, `m: (forall X : Type), (X -> X) -> X -> X` is a function that should behave parametrically for any instantiation of `X`, so by knowing that `0 = m nat S 0` I should be able to deduce that `x = m X f x` for any `x : X` and `f : X -> X`.

But I haven't seen such free theorems stated in Coq for Gallina terms. Is there an easy way to go about proving such a result without some deep embedding of a language and proving parametricity for this language?

Comment: I believe that the logic of Coq admits ad-hoc models, where parametricity does not hold. Informally, we can envision a `t : nat'` in the _model_ which behaves as zero when `X` is empty, and as one otherwise -- breaking parametricity. Such `t` is not definable in Coq, but present in some model. Hence, by soundness, we can't prove parametricity in Coq (unless we introduce new axioms). I can't justify this precisely since my knowledge of Coq models is quite limited -- hopefully others can provide more insight.

Comment: Interesting, @chi! I wasn't aware of this!

Comment: Imagine you could write in Coq something like `M = fun (T: Type) (x y: T) => if T = nat then x else y` with type `forall T, T -> T -> T`, i.e. a Church-encoded boolean. (Coq rejects this, of course.) Then, `M` would be a boolean other than true and false, violating parametricity. I'd somehow expect that some model has something like `M` inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My belief has always been that you cannot prove such free theorems from within Gallina about Gallina terms, but I don't have a definite reason why. I certainly can't imagine how this proof would work, given that there's no way to analyze functions like instances of `nat'` other than applying them.

As you mentioned, you can (in principle) do a parametricity proof for a deeply-embedded language.

Comment: There's a construction in the HoTT book of a non-parametric function from excluded middle on hProps.  Basically, you can decide for any type "is there exactly one non-identity isomorphism of this type?" because all proofs of existence of such a unique isomorphism are equal (if you assume function extensionality).  Now you have a function of type `forall T, T -> T` which is negation on `bool` and identity on anything not equivalent to `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

There are plugins for Coq to prove such parametricity theorems.
E.g. https://github.com/parametricity-coq/paramcoq
which has been superseded by 
https://template-coq.github.io/template-coq/